# Transaction does not rollback when exception occurs outside controller

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions, rollback

Transaction does not rollback when exception occurs outside controller

The methods used inside the register function are implemented in a trait, and all side methods throw an exception in case of an error.
But unfortunately, when an exception is thrown inside one of the side methods outside controller (for example: findRefererIdFromRequest() or findRefererIdFromRequest() or collectDataFromRequest()), the database return operation does not happen And the new user that was created by the create method is still inside the database and cannot be rolled back

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticationTrait;

    public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {

            # Collect data from request
            $dataCollect = $this->collectDataFromRequest($request);

            # Create a new user
            $this->createUser($dataCollect);

            # Find ReferrerID from the request by invitation code
            $referrerId = $this->findRefererIdFromRequest($request);

            # Put ReferrerId into the user profile
            $this->putReferrerId($referrerId);

            DB::commit();

            # Return success response
            return response()->json($this->registerSuccessResponse());
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }
}
```

```
trait AuthenticationTrait
{

    protected function collectDataFromRequest($request)
    {
        try {
            return collect($request->only([
                'name', 'email', 'password', 'country_id', 'language_id'
            ]));
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw new CustomException(__("The system is unable to collect input data."));
        }
    }



    protected function createUser($dataCollect)
    {
        try {

            # Generate hashed password
            $hashedPassword = bcrypt($dataCollect->get('password'));
            $dataCollect->put('password', $hashedPassword);

            # Create a new user
            $this->user = $this->userRepository->create($dataCollect->toArray());

        } catch (\Exception $th) {
            throw new CustomException(__('Sorry! The system is unable to create a new user account.'));
        }
    }



    protected function findRefererIdFromRequest($request)
    {
        # I have intentionally thrown an exception
        throw new CustomException(__("The invitation code is invalid."));
    }



    protected function putReferrerId($referrerId)
    {
        # Update user profile and put referrerId into the user profile
        $this->user->update(['referrer_id' => $referrerId]);

    }

    // Other funtions ... 

   }
```

Comment: You say the user is created therefore either `findRefererIdFromRequest` does not actually fail (i.e. no unhandled exception is thrown), or you handle any exception within that function and return anyway. It's not clear what is happening here

Comment: @apokryfos I edited my question. Please take a look again to see if I should remove exception handling.

Comment: In your code if `invitation_code` is not in the request then the result of `findRefererIdFromRequest` is `null` and no exception is thrown. It has to be more consistent. Either always throw an exception when it fails or always return null when it fails and check if the result is null in the caller

Comment: @apokryfos The null value in the findRefererIdFromRequest function is also acceptable as an allowed value and there is no problem with it.
The problem is that even if we manually throw an exception in this function, Laravel cannot roll back the transaction inside the controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

After a deep look, I realized that the database engine was on the default value, MyISAM,which does not support transactions.

In order for the transactions to be controllable, you must set the database engine to InnoDB.

Go to the database configuration file and change the database engine to InnoDB

**config/database.php**

```
 'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,

        // 'engine' => "MyISAM",
        'engine' => "InnoDB",

        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

first put your db transaction outside the try block, and as regards the exception handling in your trait function if invitation_code is true just return it. also is this method "getUserIdByInvitationCode" present in the trait?

Comment: Now, none of the functions in trait have problems and the program works properly and the null value is also acceptable, but suppose we throw an exception manually in one of the functions, the cache block is executed in the controller, but DB::rolleback does not return the transactions. . Even I put DB::begaintransaction outside the try, but it didn't work.

Comment: I edited my question. Please take a look again

Comment: make sure you are importing the the right class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: I used the same namespace

Comment: I honestly can't tell what's wrong with this code, but if you don't mind we can have a call on meet so I can review your code better google meet
https://meet.google.com/fmd-rkge-hud

Comment: Hope the DB::rollback() in the catch block solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it says that this function does not exist